# select one row on condtion

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2010

I need to make a small adjustment here and not sure if it can be done.
In the following, if there is no '001' row, then I only want 1 row for that order, but when there is 001 i do want that and the next one according to earliest time.

```
CREATE VIEW rklib.clspaytp AS Select * from
 (
     Select x.*,
     row_number() over (partition by otord#
                        order by case ottrnc when '001' then 1 else 2 end
                        , ottrnd, ottrt
                        )
                     as RowN
    from rklib.clspaytpp x
) a
 where a.RowN in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use a union such as:

favorite

I need to make a small adjustment here and not sure if it can be done. In the following, if there is no '001' row, then I only want 1 row for that order, but when there is 001 i do want that and the next one according to earliest time.

```
CREATE VIEW rklib.clspaytp AS 
    Select *
    from rklib.clspaytpp
    where ottrnc='001'
    union

    select *
    from 
    (
    select *
    from rklib.clspaytpp
    where ottrnc != '001'
    limit 1
    ) x
```